# Why the results don't disappear when I delete too fast the input in the search field? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, redux

I have an input field that maps the state and shows me the results on change:

```
if (this.state.results === "" || this.state.results === null || this.state.results === undefined){
            showResults = null;
        } else {
            let results = this.state.results.map(result => (
                <StyledLink key={result.name} to={`/game/${result.name}`}> 
                    <SearchResult
                        name={result.name}
                    />
                </StyledLink>)
            )

            showResults = <StyledResults>{results}</StyledResults>
        }
```

Everything works fine, but when I press the delete button to fast, even If the input field is empty it still shows results. It doesn't happen if I wait half a second beetween every delete press.

And this is what is what the input field triggers onChange:

```
findGames = (event) => {
    let searchText = event.target.value
    if (event.target.value) {
        let body = {
            "search_text": `${searchText}`, "fields": ["id", "name", "release_dates"]
        }
        axios.post(getGameIDUrl, body, headers)
            .then(res => res.data.filter((result) => { return result.type === "game" }))
            .then(res => this.setState({ results: res }))
            .then(console.log(this.state.results))
    } else {
        this.setState({ results: null })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to cancel previous `axios.post` request before sending another one.
In case when you delete the search term completely, `this.setState({ results: null })` is called immediately, but there are previous requests still on their way and when they come back, they set the state with undesired results.

Here's an example how to cancel a request:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the request or else you will be setting state whenever the request is returned.

Initializing and reseting state to an empty array `[]` instead of `null` may also help

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        values:'',
        results:[]
    }
    findGames = (event) => {
        if(cancel){
            cancel()
            console.log('request canceled')
        }
        setState({ value:event.target.value, results:[]})

        if(event.target.value === ''){
                return null
        }

        const getGameIDUrl = 'www.someapi.com/api'
        const body = { "search_text": `${event.target.value}`, "fields": ["id", "name", "release_dates"]}
        const headers = {Authorization:'bearer API_TOKEN'}

        axios.post(
            getGameIDUrl, 
            body, 
            {cancelToken: new CancelToken((c)=> cancel = c)},
            headers
        ).then(res =>{
            const results = res.data.filter((result) => result.type === "game" )
            this.setState({ results })
        })
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.results)

        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.findGames} value={this.state.value} />
                <StyledResults>
                    {this.state.results.map(result => (
                        <StyledLink key={result.name} to={`/game/${result.name}`}> 
                            <SearchResult
                                name={result.name}
                            />
                        </StyledLink>
                    ))}
                </StyledResults>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```